# Selecting Parcels by Watershed boundary - QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.4. I would like to select all the property parcels withing a watershed boundary, easily done with Clip. But I want to retain the complete parcels that cross the watershed boundary and not have them clipped to the boundary.

Comment: Use the Select by Location (Via Vector>Research Tool>Select by Location) then use the touch and intersect options) example > https://youtu.be/CU1A86JJMIk?t=105 when this is done you can save as a vector format.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vector -> research tools ->Select by location and set the top field to your parcels, then check the boxes for "are within" and "intersects". Set the comparing to the features from layer to your watershed.

[image]

Then, right click your parcel layer in the table of contents and go to export -> save features as. Make sure you check the box to export only selected features so that your new layer will only contain those you selected in the previous step.[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed but as the previous answer noted I clicked on Vector>Research Tool>Select by Location to get there. Thanks!